# Cluster analysis using Tableau

Tags: cluster-analysis, tableau-api, k-means

I am using Tableau version 2020.3. In most of the tutorials, the data panel on the left-hand side consists of dimensions and measures but in the 2020.3 version, it is replaced with the "Table" panel which divides both dimensions and measures. After Clustering I am not able to drag the cluster into the data panel to proceed further with the cluster analysis process.

[image]

Kindly help me with this cluster analysis problem.

Comment: I rechecked in my tableau v2020.3, I am able to do it.  Please re-do

Comment: I got it thank u so much